# implementing uitabbar to uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4, uitabbar

I want to put a uitabbar into a section in uitableview, I have hard time looking a way for it, since I just started doing XCODE in less than a month. Anyone there know the solution for it? Any help is appreciated, and if possible, could you share a link for the tutorial or examples as well. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in this way. They both are different things but you can have UITableView inside the uitabbar view. But vica-versa is not allowed ...this is not feasible and also not proper as per apple's guideline. So, please make sure not to use in this way...rather go for some other alternative :

like put Custom UIToolBar in header of tableView , having look & feels like Tabbar.

Comment: Yes, having a toolbar is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a tab bar into a tableview.
I you want to use a tab bar, use it as a sub view of a UIView.

Comment: so you mean I can insert a view into table cell?

Comment: I have not tried it but you can try creating a custom tableviewcell with a view including a tab bar. But why do you want a tab bar in a table view?

Comment: Because I saw a groupon apps, it looks like they put a tabbar inside a tablecell, and I feel like trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

The UITabBar is supposed to contain other views. So no, you cannot add it to your table view. To get the look and feel of the Groupon app, there are two things you could do:
1. Create a custom tableviecell as advised above.
2. Since the toolbar (which looks like a tabbar) is outside the actual table, you can have it as a separate view and reduce the size of the table to accommodate it. Or add the toolbar to the footer view of the table.